# Android 4.0.3 emulator: install fails with "permission revoke"

Tags: android, android-emulator

Running my app on the 4.0.3 emulator typically works fine, but once in a blue moon it abruptly fails, and from then on, keeps failing. The console doesn't give any especially useful information:

> [2012-03-02 12:05:31 - MyApp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
>   [2012-03-02 12:05:31 - MyApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
>   [2012-03-02 12:05:31 - MyApp] Launch canceled!

But unfortunately, neither does Logcat:

> W/ActivityManager(1589): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MyApp.apk

The only way I've managed to fix this so far is to delete the emulator and create a new one, or clear the user data from the emulator prior to starting it:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By deleting the dalvik cache, I managed to resolve the problem. In the terminal, I entered:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell rm -r /data/dalvik-cache/*
```

Comment: Excellent technic. For Rooted devices, a restart in recovery mode will show an option to do it without ADB. (but in this case, for AVDs, then ADB is the only option)