# Android + Stage3D - empty screen

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, emulation

I'm trying to figure out how to write apps for Android using Adobe Air. I've choosen Axel Framework (simple game engine based on Stage3D) and FlashDevelop as my tools. I wrote my first app which should display an image and some text on screen. When I run this app in desktop mode, it works. Unfortunately when I install it on Android emulator it displays only blank screen (with color specified in [SWF] tag). I really don't know what's wrong.

**Addtional compile arguments:** -swf-version=13

**Target framework:** AIR mobile 3.3

**application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0">

<id>air.TestAndroidAxl</id>
<versionNumber>0.1</versionNumber>
<supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
<filename>TestAndroidAxl</filename>
<name>TestAndroid_Axl</name>

<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true"android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
    </manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>

<initialWindow>
     <title>TestAndroid_Axl</title>
     <content>TestAndroidAxl.swf</content>
     <visible>true</visible>
     <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
     <!--<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>-->
     <!--<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>-->
     <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
     <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
     <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
 </initialWindow>

<icon>
    <image48x48>icons/icon_48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>icons/icon_57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>icons/icon_72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>icons/icon_114.png</image114x114>
    <image512x512>icons/icon_512.png</image512x512>
 </icon>
 </application>
```

**Main.as**

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

public class Main extends Sprite {

    public function Main() : void {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);

        // touch or gesture?
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        // entry point
        var game : AxlGame = new AxlGame();
        addChild(game);
    }

    private function deactivate(e:Event) : void {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }

}
```

**AxllGame.as**

```
import org.axgl.Ax;

public class AxlGame extends Ax {

    public function AxlGame() {
        super(PlayState);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it on emulator with GPU emulation. Here's how to set it up:

1. Add Android 4.0.3 (or later) image.
2. Edit the image. Next to “Hardware:”, Select “New…”
3. Add “GPU emulation”.
4. Set its value to “Yes”.

Comment: I found something interesting in logcat:

    W/ActivityManager(   82): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/TestAndroidAxl.apk
    W/ActivityManager(   82): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/TestAndroidAxl.apk
    I/PackageManager(   82): Removing non-system package:air.air.TestAndroidAxl
    I/ActivityManager(   82): Force stopping package air.air.TestAndroidAxl uid=10044

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532653/android-4-0-3-emulator-install-fails-with-permission-revoke ?

Comment: I find out that the error is made by stage3D.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, ...); But I can't repair it.