# android eclipse INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_CERTIFICATE_ENCODING

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

Not sure how this came about, I was building a project fine, then next time I built it, within 2 mins, suddenly this started happening in eclipse:

```
[2012-07-26 12:48:02 - project] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_CERTIFICATE_ENCODING
[2012-07-26 12:48:02 - project] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-07-26 12:48:02 - project] Launch canceled!
```

Adb output as:

```
07-26 12:48:01.656: W/ActivityManager(346): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/xxxx.apk
07-26 12:48:01.726: W/ActivityManager(346): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/xxxx.apk
07-26 12:48:01.781: D/dalvikvm(346): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346): Exception reading /data/app/vmdl-883532656.tmp
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346): java.io.IOException: global_list_ch
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):  ild_row_bck.png.png
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346): SHA1-Digest
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at java.util.jar.InitManifest.readName(InitManifest.java:130)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at java.util.jar.InitManifest.readHeader(InitManifest.java:104)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at java.util.jar.InitManifest.initEntries(InitManifest.java:69)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:221)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:120)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:296)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:608)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:7249)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$1600(PackageManagerService.java:159)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:5546)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I've tried the obvious, restart device, `adb uninstall com.project.xxxx`, restart adb, restart eclipse, `android update project -p ./`

The real kicker is this project is only broken, I can build any of the others, go figure!

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: I know you said you restarted adb, but did you clear the cache as well? Someone else had the same error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532653/android-4-0-3-emulator-install-fails-with-permission-revoke) and apparently fixed it with a cache reset.

Comment: Yup tried that, no help.

Comment: Good to hear! I went ahead and posted that as an answer so people directed to this question in the future can see it a bit more prominently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK finally found the issue after taking a break and looking again:

```
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346): java.io.IOException: global_list_ch
07-26 12:48:01.781: W/PackageParser(346):  ild_row_bck.png.png
```

I saw this then looked at my resources, I has somehow managed to enter a new line on one of my files. looked like:

```
ic_something.png
ic_something_else.png
```

As the file name, What's odd is that this compiles fine, so I never thought to look at the resources.

Hoping that might help someone in the future.

I have raised an bug for this, it's eclipse specific: [Eclipse Bug: 386045](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386045)

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Converted from a comment.

I know you said you restarted adb, but did you clear the cache as well? Someone else had the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532653/android-4-0-3-emulator-install-fails-with-permission-revoke) and apparently fixed it with a cache reset. Specifically, they entered the following in the terminal:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell rm -r /data/dalvik-cache/*
```