# Android "No content provider found or permission revoke" with android 4

Tags: android, android-emulator, permissions, android-contentprovider, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an android application that works perfectly on android 2-2 and 2-3. But when i try to install the application on android 4-0 or 4-2-2 i twice get the following error:

No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/myapp.apk

I found out that others had a similar problem and i tried the solutions given in the following links:

[Cannot install APK on Android device through Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse/8646393#8646393) 
for this one i have to say that my device is not rooted. i try to run my app on a emulator.

[Android 4.0.3 emulator: install fails with "permission revoke"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532653/android-4-0-3-emulator-install-fails-with-permission-revoke/9532683#9532683)

[Android error message on install "no content provider found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073358/android-error-message-on-install-no-content-provider-found)
here i tried another phone for the emulator. originally i used the galaxy nexus but i also tried with nexus 7

[Android "No content provider found for permission revoke"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550798/android-no-content-provider-found-for-permission-revoke)
last but not least i tried to add the main action to the "androidmanifest.xml" i'm not sure if i did it the right way here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.service"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="6" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Is there still something wrong with my manifest.xml file or do you have another idea why i can run this application on android 2 but not on 4?

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and none of the current answers did the trick. This worked for me:

adb install -s C:/path/to/your/package/bin/MyApp.apk

'-s' puts it on the sd card, I'm not sure if that's necessary in your case.

Comment: I fixed this problem in a similar way, by adding 200MB to the SD card of my AVD definition.

Comment: I get **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION]**

Answer (score 1):

This message may be an indication of insufficient internal storage on the device. There is a certain level at which Android starts complaining and won't install new apps. I saw "No content provider found for permission revoke" accompanied by errors like "insufficient space", or "Installation error code: -20", or "INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE", or "Package install status for  is -20" -- all meaning the same thing. In my case, the solution was to free up some storage (clear cache/data, uninstall some apps).

Answer (score 0):

Add some memory to your Virtual Device and uninstall your app. Reinstall, and voilà! It worked for me, and I wasnt even using storage on my app.

Answer (score 0):

**Red Herring: “No content provider found or permission revoke”**

I've found that message to be extraneous.  In the package install case I investigated it's just a warning message that the package URI doesn't contain an 'authority' (userid/password) portion.  handleStartCopy(), (in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java) does:

```
mContext.grantUriPermission(DEFAULT_CONTAINER_PACKAGE, mPackageURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

some work, then:

```
mContext.revokeUriPermission(mPackageURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

the message is true, but inconsequential.  (removeUriPermission() is in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/ActivityManagerService.java)